# Split off the contents of a variable after the last space in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program in python that'll split off the contents after the last space in a string. e.g. if a user enters "this is a test", I want it to return "test". I'm stuck on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy and efficient with `str.rsplit`.

```
>>> x = 'this is a test'
>>> x.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]  # Splits at most once from right on whitespace runs
'test'
```

Alternate:

```
>>> x.rpartition(' ')[-1]  # Splits on the first actual space found
'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "this is a test"
lastWord = string.rsplit()[-1]
print lastWord

'test'
```

Comment: Using `string.rsplit` without `maxsplit` parameter is the same as `string.split` without paramaters

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and most efficient way:

```
>>> "this is a test".rpartition(' ')[-1]
'test'
```

---

```
>>> help(str.rpartition)

Help on method_descriptor:

rpartition(...)
    S.rpartition(sep) -> (head, sep, tail)

    Search for the separator sep in S, starting at the end of S, and return
    the part before it, the separator itself, and the part after it.  If the
    separator is not found, return two empty strings and S.
```